# closed dropdown while scrolling pop-up window in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, angularjs, popup

I have written the code for `<ng-select>` dropdown in popup I need to closed dropdown when I scrolling the popup window, can anyone help to get the result? in angular

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select
Ng-Select has its own method - Close(). You can call this when scroll event is fired on your window.

Comment: can you please provide code reference where implemented this?

Comment: same applies to you. Can you please provide your Code as well ??